# Diagonalizable matrix with parameters

Tags: matrices

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
    -b & -b & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & -4 & 4 \\
     0 & 0 & b & -b \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I have this matrix and I need to find the values for $b$ that this matrix won't 
be diagonalizable.

For what I got this matrix is diagonalizable for every $b$ value.

Please write me also the final answer, thank you very much.

Comment: What did you get for the eigenvalues?

Comment: Perhaps you’d care to explain why you think this matrix is always diagonalizable.

Comment: I got$$ (x+2)(x-2b)(x^2+xb+4x+8b)$$

Why it's not always diagonalizable? can you explain?

Comment: maybe I was wrong in the determinant, that's why I wanted another view on this

Comment: You can’t tell from just the determinant. Both $\small{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}}$ and $\small{\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}}$ have the same eigenvalues and thus the same determinant, but the second one isn’t diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given matrix is a blocks one, so it is diagonalizable iff each block is, and the characteristic polynomials of each block are:

$$\begin{cases}\;\text{Upper Block:}&\;p_1(x)=(x+2)(x+b)-2b=x(x+b+2)\\{}\\
\text{Lower Block:}&p_2(x)=(x+4)(x+b)-4b=x(x+b+4)\end{cases}$$

Thus: in case $\;b=-2(\text{ or}\;-4)\;$, the upper block or the lower block isn't diagonalizable, as then we get a nilpotent non-zero matrix. In any other case ( i.e., $\;b\neq-2,-4\;$) , both blocks have two different eigenvalues and are thus diagonalizable, and then also the $\;4\times4\;$ matrix is.

Comment: thank you very much. What's the smallest eigenvalue of this matrix in his absolute value?

Comment: @GhnbTrcv Weird question as it is obvious from the answer: zero, of course.

Comment: I didn't know if zero can be an answer, ty.

Comment: then I need to find the self vector for 0. $$V1=32  $$ $$ V2+V3=-12$$

Comment: @GhnbTrcv The characteristic polynomial has $\;x\;$ as one of its factors and thus zero is one of its roots...

Comment: yea ok, can you help me find the self vector for 0?

Comment: @GhnbTrcv Try with a new question. This is already answered.

Comment: reached my limit tho